# TAB key locked out for .h files (but not .cpp) in Netbeans 8.0.2

Tags: netbeans

Typing in .h file in Netbeans 8.0.2:  I've gotten wedged in a weird mode where the TAB key does no insertions at all.  ENTER causes auto-indent, but TAB key on blank line, after end of statement, inside comment...anywhere, causes no TAB and no space insertions whatsoever.
It works OK in the .cpp files, so it's not the keyboard.

Tool->Option->Editor->Formatting settings are:

Language: All Languages  Category: Tabs & Indents
[  ] Expand Tabs to Spaces  #Spaces/Indent: 4   Tab size:  8
 ^ think I tried this one both ways

Language:  C++
[ X ] Expand Tabs to Spaces  #Spaces/Indent: 4   Tab size:  8

Language:  C/C++ Header
[  ] Expand Tabs to Spaces  #Spaces/Indent: 4   Tab size:  8
but these are greyed out, unable to be modified.

Hitting a TAB key should always insert either a TAB character or a series of spaces, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's a tiny checkbox **[X] Override Global Options** above the settings in *Language: C/C++ Header* that was causing the grey-out.  When I set this, the TAB keys started working in .h files again.  But even after clearing it again, I'm presently unable to replicate the previous behavior, so it seems like perhaps it's a bug, not a feature.  Anyway, try Override Global Options and then the TAB seems to start working again.